# assign list items to model properties

Tags: asp.net-mvc

MODEL

```
    namespace CG.MyPollSurveyAdmin.Models
    {
        public class CompletePollSurvey
        {
        public long PollSurveyID { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public List<OptionData> Options { get; set; }
        public List<QuestionData> QuestionDetails { get; set; }
    }
    public class QuestionData
    {
        public string QuestionName { get; set; }
        public long QuestionID { get; set; }
        public int OptionID { get; set; }
        public string OptionType { get; set; }
        public string Option_1 { get; set; }
        public string Option_2 { get; set; }
        public string Option_3 { get; set; }
        public string Option_4 { get; set; }
        public string Option_5 { get; set; }
    }
}
```

CONTROLLER

```
  private List<Question> GetQuestionsById(long PollSurveyId)
        {
            MemoryStream outMemoryStream = RESTFulServiceHelper.Instance.ExecuteGetMethod(Constants.Method_GetAllQuestions, Convert.ToString(Session[Constants.NTLoginID]));

            DataContractJsonSerializer outDataContractJsonSerialize = new DataContractJsonSerializer(typeof(List<Question>));
            List<Question> lstQuestions = outDataContractJsonSerialize.ReadObject(outMemoryStream) as List<Question>;
            List<Question> question = lstQuestions.Where(p => p.PollSurveyID == PollSurveyId).ToList();
            return question;

            }
public ActionResult Help(long PollSurveyID=2)
        {
            if (Session[Constants.Session_IsAdmin] != null && Convert.ToBoolean(Session[Constants.Session_IsAdmin]))

            {
                CompletePollSurvey completePollSurvey = new CompletePollSurvey();
                List<Question> question = GetQuestionsById(Convert.ToInt64(PollSurveyID));

                return View(completePollSurvey);
            }
            else
            {
                return RedirectToAction("Login");
            }
        }
```

Here is the model and controller of my program. Till now I'm getting All the questions for **poll id=2** but I'm having difficulty in retrieving element from **Question** List and assign it to Model List elements(or list to list assignment). 
For e.g I have 5 questions for **Poll=2** and in each question there are 5 options

Comment: Your model contains a collection property which is `List<QuestionData>` and `QuestionData` contains a property which is `Question`, so I assume you want `completePollSurvey.QuestionDetails = question.Select(x => new QuestionData{ Question = x });`

Comment: @StephenMuecke actually By **Question** I meant Common Entities Class which is receiving list from DB which i have to assign to model in controller

Comment: Which is exactly what I showed you.

Comment: `completePollSurvey.QuestionDetails = question.Select(x => new QuestionData { QuestionID = x.QuestionID })` did this and got an error "An explicit conversion exists" @StephenMuecke

Comment: Read my comment again - its `new QuestionData{ Question = x })`! (and I have no idea what your `QuestionID` property of `Question` is - but it would give that error if its not `long`)

Comment: @StephenMuecke yeah firstly I did as u told but I got the error `Error CS0029 Cannot implicitly convert type 'CG.MyPollSurvey.Common.Entities.Question' to 'string'` that's why tried in another way. Also I Have checked QuestionId is in long the detailed error is `'Cannot convert Models.QuestionData to System .Collections.Generic.List<Models.QuestionData>'`

Comment: `'Cannot convert Models.QuestionData to System .Collections.Generic.List<Models.QuestionData>` is because somewhere you are trying to turn a single question into a list of questions, which is not logical.

Comment: Above set of code is the only thing I have tried yet. Don't know where things are going wrong @ADyson

Comment: Well I've just given you a big clue. And the compiler should be telling you on which line that error occurs. You can't turn individual items into lists. You can _add_ them to lists, but you can't just cast from a single item to a list. I can't go to the market and turn a single apple into a basket of apples. I can go and buy a basket and then add an apple to it, but I can't just make the apple into a basket by magic. That's what your code appears to be trying to do.

Comment: @ADyson yeah I got that one. Totally understood what I was doing wrong and I have removed that. But my main aim is to assign DB list items to my model list and still I'm unable to do that.

Comment: Well, your questions are of type `Question`, and your model question list appears to be of type `QuestionData`. So you'll have to write some code to map the values from one type to the other. If you like you can use a tool like AutoMapper (https://automapper.org/) to help automate the conversion process. Otherwise you just have to write some code to loop each instance of `Question` and copy the relevant properties into an instance of `QuestionData`